# Magento 2.0.3 Upgrade fails - Conflicting component dependencies

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento-2.0.3

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.0.2 to 2.0.3

The readiness check fails as below:

[image]

Any Idea how to fix it? All crons have been set and permissions are also fine.

Comment: it's looks like bug. Can you create issue ing github?

Comment: @KAndy, issue created at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3173#issuecomment-203791016

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @zus Increase php memory_limit

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to pass just by increasing my php.ini memory_limit to 1024M .

Comment: i will change memory_limit=1024M in php.ini,but it show same error.